# Custom Deserialiser to parse complex Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to deserialise below Json

```
{
    "Student": [
        {
            "Number": "12345678",
            "Name": "abc"
            "Country": "IN",
            "AreaOfInterest": [
                {
                    “FootBall”: “Yes”,
                    “Cricket”: “No”
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hasMore": false,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "kind": "collection"
        }
    ]
}
```

into below POJO

```
class {
   private String number;
   private String name;
   private String footBall;
}
```

I have written Gson custom deserialiser to lift up **AreaOfInterest** as below

```
public List<? extends Student> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    var jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    Stream<JsonElement> student = StreamSupport.stream(jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Student").spliterator(), true);
    Stream<JsonElement> areaOfInterest = StreamSupport.stream(jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Student").get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("AreaOfInterest").getAsJsonArray().spliterator(), true);


    Stream.concat(student,areaOfInterest)
                                .map(it -> context.deserialize(it, Student.class))
                                .map(Student.class::cast)
                                .collect(List.collector())
}
```

But deserialiser returning two objects of Student instead of one, one is all fields are null except **footBall** other is actual *student* except **footBall** as null, any help how to get single object with all the fields will be of great help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be your exact answer, but it might be simpler to use gson to obtain a map and construct your pojo from that map. Alternatively, if you don't like the map, create a pojo that looks like your JSON and map that pojo to the pojo you want.

Background/Reasoning: GSON is the mapper of your choice right now, but might be changed to something else, eg. Jackson, and all of your custom, framework specific mappers will need to be converted/changed if that happens. Using gson to create an object, that looks like the source, and map that to your custom POJO in your controller will make your codes intention clear and your code more resilient to framework changes.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I agree but plan here is to use *Student* custom deserialiser as a generic one, like **AreaOfInterets** some other complex *JsonElement* might get added to original one, so am just trying to make it as generic as possible.

Comment: That's fine mate, just be aware of the cost - benefit relation. If it's worth it, happy hacking 